# How to sort a large table in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have about 4GB data stored in Google's BigQuery in the following format:

```
   uuid    |   entity_name    |    property    |    value   
---------------------------------------------------------------
  abc      |   Person         |   first_name   |  John
  def      |   Person         |   age          |  45
  abc      |   Person         |   age          |  26
  def      |   Person         |   first_name   |  Mary
...
```

I want to get paginated results sorted by uuid. However, as per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#largequeryresults), **it is not possible to use ORDER BY or GROUP BY when the flag "allowLargeResults" is set to true.** And of course querying such large table requires that. Is there a workaround for this scenario? I attempted to do client-side sorting however after successfully fetching the first few pages it raises an error "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host".

Here's my query job:

```
query = 'SELECT * FROM [Users.Events] ORDER BY uuid'

query_request = {
    'jobReference': {
        'projectId': project_id,
        'job_id': str(uuid.uuid4())
    },
    'configuration': {
        'query': {
            'query': query,
            'priority': 'BATCH' if BATCH_QUERY else 'INTERACTIVE',
            'allowLargeResults' : True,
            'destinationTable': {
                'projectId': project_id,
                'datasetId': 'CrunchBase',
                'tableId': 'AllProperties_query'
            },
            'createDisposition': 'CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
            'writeDisposition': 'WRITE_TRUNCATE',
        }
    }
}

query_job = service.jobs().insert(
    projectId=project_id,
    body=query_request).execute(num_retries=2)

poll_job(service, query_job)
```

Result:

```
RuntimeError: {u'reason': u'resourcesExceeded', u'message': u'Resources exceeded during query execution.', u'location': u'query'}
```

---

**EDIT: Attempting to sort within partition**

I can potentially solve the problem if I figure out how to partition by entity_name and sort by uuid, however the following query does not work:

```
SELECT
  uuid, entity_name, property, value
OVER
  (PARTITION BY entity_name ORDER BY uuid) AS entities
FROM [CrunchBase.AllProperties];
```

Results:

```
Query Failed
Error: Missing function in Analytic Expression at: 1.15 - 1.70
```

Comment: I think, you are mistaken about `GROUP BY`!
As of `ORDER BY` - when you set "`allowLargeResults`" to true  - what you actually do is - you allow BigQuery to compute result in parallel. As you can imagine - this is not possible if you use top level ORDER BY. Thus the limitation

Comment: I get that it scans the rows in parallel, I am looking for a workaround for this scenario... Would it be possible to e.g. partition the data by entity_name and order each partition by uuid?

Comment: The answer depends on why you need to sort the table. If it is because you need to export it outside of BigQuery - there is a workaround solution. But if it sorted data will stay within BigQuery - can you explain why you need sorting ?

Comment: @MoshaPasumansky: Basically it would make it easier to export data outside BigQuery. If the rows were sorted by uuid, I could just scan through the results and create new entities on the go. If they are not sorted, a single entity may have properties in the 1st and last row which means I would have to store all results before start exporting.

Comment: You should see the documentation on BigQuery or SQL in general to see that the way you're using partition isn't correct. `OVER (PARTITION ... )` expressions should follow a function field, like `SUM(value)`, etc.

Comment: Can you concatenate all property=value pairs for an entity onto a single row? Then you don't care about ordering since you have one row == one entity.

Comment: Another potential solution: use https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/ to process your bigquery table. It can group by uuid and then you can "create new entities" during the reduce phase where all your property-value pairs are processed. This might work if whatever processing you are trying to do can be expressed within the dataflow framework.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question in your edit, you need to actually specify an analytic function to apply over that ordered partition. Since you just want the current value for each row, you can use `lead(x, 0)`.

For your query, you'd write something like this:

```
SELECT
  uuid, entity_name,
  LEAD(property, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY entity_name ORDER BY uuid) AS cur_property,
  LEAD(value, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY entity_name ORDER BY uuid) AS cur_value,
FROM [CrunchBase.AllProperties]
```